# Error after install

Tags: php, laravel

After creating a fresh installation of laravel 4, installing all the composer dependancies and going to the url where the installation is located I get this error:

> ErrorException: Warning: file_put_contents(/var/www/mysite/app/config/../storage/meta/services.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/mysite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php line 77

Any idea's why or what this error is, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Ahh, I always have this "issue" when starting a Laravel project. CHMOD the "storage" folder and I think you should be fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by running chmod -R 775 on the storage directory.

Comment: I did this, then had to run php artisan cache:clear as well, and it started working.